# semiclassical principal symbol

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, microlocal-analysis

What is the semiclassical principal symbol $\sigma_h$ of the operator $h^2\Delta-1$ (here $\Delta=-\sum_j\partial^{2}_{x_j}$)?  $h^2\Delta-1$ is a second order semiclassical partial differential operator, so it makes sense to me that $\sigma_h(h^2\Delta-1)=|\xi|^2$.  But I've read that $\sigma_h(h^2\Delta-1)=|\xi|^2-1$.  Since the principal symbol is supposed to be the ***top*** order part of the total symbol (as I understand it), why is the $-1$ included in the principal symbol?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the subprincipal symbol has to not only be of smaller order in $|\xi|$ but also has to be of smaller order in $h$. Hence $-1$ cannot be in the subprincipal symbol since it is not $O(h)$.

Answer (score 0):

In the semi-classical setting, here is a simple rule to find the principal symbol:

Couple each differentiation operator with an $h$ like $(hD_x)^\alpha$, then those terms has no extra power in $h$ is left as principal symbol (of course, with $(hD_x)^\alpha$ replaced by $\xi^\alpha$). And here 1 is a term like this.

One thing you need to be careful, is that there might be some implicit 'large parameters' that is assumed to be order like $\Omega(h^{-1})$, so you need to cancel this order with $h$ to see which terms are really in the right order.